# JWT Revoke Refresh Token

Tags: node.js, jwt

I'm building a Node.js API service.  I'm issuing a JWT access token that expires every 5 minutes, a refresh token that expires in a month, and /fetch-access route to get a new access token when called from the SPA/client.

Now I'm using a database to store a list of recently revoked refresh tokens that an administrative user can populate by some administrative action (i.e. "suspend account", "change permissions", etc.).

My assumptions were that I would produce the same JWT token string value, store that in the database and query the database for that value when the /fetch-access route is called.  However, what I realize now is that; at the time that the administrative user is revoking the JWT, I have no way to replicate the same JWT string value at that point in time.

To illustrate my point;

> ```
> const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
> let refresh_token_on_login = jwt.sign({user: 'bob'}, 'secret123', {expiresIn: '7d'})
> let refresh_token_on_revoke = jwt.sign({user: 'bob'}, 'secret123', {expiresIn: '7d'})
>
> console.log(refresh_token_on_login) 
> //eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0ZXN0Ijp0cnVlLCJpYXQiOjE2MDA4Mzg2NzUsImV4cCI6MTYwMTQ0MzQ3NX0.X2zBWVr5t3olb5GsPebHULh-j1-iiuyjJmb98jzlZ2Q
>
> console.log(refresh_token_on_revoke)
> //eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0ZXN0Ijp0cnVlLCJpYXQiOjE2MDA4Mzg3MTMsImV4cCI6MTYwMTQ0MUxM30.4LDBJv4qrLLzOieDtyXu8vWqJ1EY75vShpUWiX7jepQgg
> ```

In order for the administrator to invalidate refresh token that was issued to the user at a prior time, the revoke key cannot be the actual token string, but some other value that gets saved somewhere in the database at the time of login (i.e. UserModel = { last_issued_refresh: 'xyz'}).  That same value needs to be embedded in the refresh token itself to be used in checking the black-listed tokens upon /fetch-access requests.

Are my assumptions correct?  Is this the only way to do this, or am I missing some key point in how the refresh token gets revoked (by a user other than the client user - such as admin)

Comment: May be https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/.